# How to prove the ratio of two random variables is also a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

If $X, Y$ are two random variables, how to prove $X/Y$ is also a random variable? 
I understand I have to prove $\{\omega \in \Omega;\frac{X}{Y}(\omega) \leq t \}\in F$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space and $F$ is the $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$, but I don't know how to do this and what sufficient condition that $X/Y$ is a random variable?

Comment: Hint: For every Borel function $u$, $u(X,Y)$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 0):

if we know that the product of two r.v. is a r.v. itself, then the problem is reduced to show that if $Y$ is a r.v. then $1/Y$ is a r.v. (with $Y \neq 0$), that should be easy

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ be a random variable then it's easy to show that for each measurable function $f$ also $f\circ Y$ is a random variable due to $(f\circ Y)^{-1}(A) = Y^{-1}\left(f^{-1}(A)\right)$.
Because $f$ is measurable so is $B=f^{-1}(A)$ for each measurable $A$ and because $Y$ is a RV so is $Y^{-1}(B) = Y^{-1}\left(f^{-1}(A)\right)$.

Take $f: \Bbb R \setminus\{0\} \to  \Bbb R \setminus\{0\}, f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ which is measurable because it's continuous gives you that $\frac{1}{Y}$ is a RV.

To show that the product of two RV is a RV is the same argument for the continuous hence measurable function $u(x,y) = xy$ and the fact that $(XY)^{-1} = \binom{X}{Y}^{-1}\circ u^{-1}$ and $\binom{X}{Y}^{-1}(A \times B) = \binom{X^{-1}(A)}{Y^{-1}(B)}$.

Consider that $\{A \times B \;|\; A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)\}$ is a generator of $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$ which is stable under intersections so it's enough to show it for these kinds of sets…